# Why does null-propagation of Nullable<T> return T and not Nullable<T>?

Tags: c#, nullable, null-propagation-operator

Consider the following code:

```
Nullable<DateTime> dt;

dt. <-- Nullable<DateTime>
dt?. <-- DateTime
```

Null propagation returns `T`, rather than `Nullable<T>`.

How and why?

Comment: Well, adding `.Value` each time would be pointless if it was only invoked when there was a value, so presumably they decided to treat it a bit like a lifted operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the way null propagation works if the object on the left hand side of the `?.` is null the object on the right hand side is never executed. Because you know the right hand side can never be null it strips off the `Nullable` as a convenience so you don't need to type `.Value` every time.

You could think of it as

```
public static T operator ?.(Nullable<U> lhs, Func<U,T> rhs) 
    where T: class
    where U: struct
{
    if(lhs.HasValue)
    {
        return rhs(lhs.Value);
    }
    else 
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

The above code is not legal C#, but that is the behavior it does.

Comment: When you say "it strips off the Nullable" is it essentially syntactic sugar?

Comment: yes, it is essentially that. It does the `.Value` call for you so you don't need to.

Comment: I see. I'm assuming the code above doesn't work because the null propagation operator can't be overloaded?

Comment: I mean, since it does the same thing the 'normal' way round, returning a Nullable<value_type> if you use it like `bool? value = myObject?.booleanValue`, it's not too surprising that it must work the other way round too.
And yeah, you can't overload the operator luckily, that would be hell :D

Comment: I could make overloads for the combinations of `T` and `U` being all the choices of class and struct but I don't know how helpful that would be. If you would like them I can add them.